# Over-riding Django-allauth login/ registration urls with custom url/ pages

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have configured django-allauth for login through Facebook, Twitter and Google.

However, django-allauth accepts login request only at `/accounts/login/`, sign up request only at `/accounts/signup/` etc. 
I have a modal form for login and registration on my home page and I want to use only that.

[image]

How do I use django-allauth system to allow login ( both social and custom)/ registration etc from the modal form on my home page? 
I'm looking for mechanism to override django-allauth's urls and substitute them with my pages/ urls.

The code is [here](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/ECommerce-Django)

The modal form HTML is [here](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/ECommerce-Django/blob/master/ecomweb/static/modals/login.html).

This question is perhaps similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695761/django-allauth-sign-up-login-and-social-connect-into-one-page). However the answer in the question isnt too understandable.

Following a few answers, I have made these changes:

```
#views.py
def logreg(request):
    context = {
        'login_form': MyLoginForm(), 
        'signup_form': MySignupForm()
    }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

#In URL Patterns of urls.py
url(r'^login/', logreg, name='login'),

In Index ( from where call to the modal is to be made):
<p>Welcome visitor <a href="#" data-modal-url="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> or <a href="#">Register</a></p>
```

All this work resulted in this mess:

```
    Internal Server Error: /login/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'ecomweb.home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I'm nuts to what is happening.

Comment: Is there a URL pattern for 'home' in your urls.py and/or a `{% url 'home' %}` somewhere in your template? Can you show a bit more of your code?

Comment: Did you solve this? I ran into the same problem

Comment: @user3667089 Any luck with the solution??? I am facing similar issues...

Comment: @Jayesh no I haven't.... let me know when you solve this

Comment: @user3667089 Have you tried http://api.jquery.com/load/ ???

Comment: @user3667089 I was able to load the all-auth login page inside the modal popup successfully. But the thing is that it loads it fully along with the base.html

Comment: @user3667089 I have edited the default login.html of django all-auth by removing the base extends and adding the modal popup headers. Now the template loads pretty fine but at the same time I am losing the non-ajax view.

Answer (score 11):

Well, it is pretty easy solution.

in urls.py do this:

```py
from allauth.account.views import LoginView, SignupView 

urlpatterns = [
   ...
   url(r'^customurl/login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="custom_login" ),
   url(r'^customurl/signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name="custom_singup" ),
   ...

]
```

and in html create form:

```html
<form action="{% url 'custom_signup' %}" method="POST">
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>


<form action="{% url 'custom_login' %}" method="POST">
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

Comment: The modal form does not have a URL. Its triggered when visitor clicks on 'Login'. What to do in such a case?

Comment: Why don't you make the modal form an `<iframe src="{% url 'custom_login' %}"></iframe>`?

Comment: @raphv: That mutilates the page look (https://postimg.org/image/m14gqfinl/)
As per your suggestion, I replaced with `<p>Welcome visitor <a href="#" data-modal-url="{% static 'modals/login.html' %}">Login</a> or <a href="#">Register</a></p>` with `<iframe src="{% url 'login' %}">Login</iframe>`

Comment: @raphv: I added the iframe to the login.html modal too. Its not how I would like to handle the form. Are there alternatives?
https://postimg.org/image/j4drf4y69/

Answer (score 3):

For using allauth's login or signup functionality, you do not have to override urls associated with it.

Just *submit* your form to the urls associated with the allauth like

```
<form action="/accounts/login/?next{{request.path}}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- Your form elements here -->
</form>

<form action="/accounts/signup/?next{{request.path}}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- Your form elements here -->
</form>
```

Its upto you to use **?next{{request.path}}**, if you want your user to stay on the same page from where he logged in.

**Updated Answer:**

First of all don't store templates inside the static folder, its not a good practice.

As I already pointed out that for using allauth's `views` functionality, you don't necessarily have to override its `url` and `views` (unless for specific reasons).

1. Inside your templates folder create a new folder `account` with
   `login.html` file.
2. Paste your html login `code` in this `login.html` file.
3. Delete your method custom login method `logreg` and its related
   `url` and `imports`.
4. Change all references that point to your custom login method
   `logreg` with  `account_login` (allauth's login name).
5. In your base.html - replace {% static 'login.html' %} to {% url
   'account_login' %}.

And you are ready to go.

But you have to handle the html for the case when a user tries to visit `/accounts/login/` page.

*Moreover you can always use thefallback approach to submit your modal login form via ajax request to accounts/login/ and handle success() and error().*

Comment: Hello, i want it to stay on the same page too even if the auth fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to call django-allauth's forms in your home view

In `views.py`:

```
from django.allauth.account.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm

def home(request):
    context = {
        'login_form': LoginForm(),
        'signup_form': SignupForm(),
    }
    return render(request, "myapp/home.html", context)
```

In your home template (e.g. `templates/myapp/home.html`):

```
<form action="{% url 'account_login' %}?next={% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{login_form}}
</form>
<form action="{% url 'account_signup' %}?next={% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{login_form}}
</form>
```

Then the last thing is that you'll have Django-allauth's `blank` templates by default, but you can override them by creating a `base.html` template in a directory called `account` your application template directory (e.g. `myproject/templates/account/base.html`. I recommend extending from the same template you're using for your home template.
Make sure this `account/base` template has the following block, which will be filled in by django-allauth:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Overriding allauth's templates this way (which you may want to do on a per-endpoint basis if you wish to) will only work if you load your own app **before** `allauth` in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'myapp',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    ...
```

Comment: The problem is that it I want the login form on a modal ( modal does not have a URL but a different html file. It super imposes on the index itself as seen in the image). 
So how do I render the view to the modal without a url.py entry?

Comment: By calling the form in the view and template, as in the first part of my answer.

Comment: But how do I call it from the template when there is no URL! 

`<p>Welcome visitor <a href="#" data-modal-url="<what-to-put-here">Login</a> </p>`

Comment: Either you create a login view and you can associate it with an URL
**OR** you make it part of your home view, as indicated in my answer, make it hidden by default, and show it when people click on login, e.g. with `<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('loginform').style.display='block';return false;">Login</a>`

Comment: I tried the latter part of your suggestion (make it part of your home view,make it hidden by default, and show it when people click on login) but that doesnt make it a modal window.
https://postimg.org/image/ucvo1jg0n/

Comment: Well, it makes it modal if you put it in the right place on the page with the right CSS styling. If you look at the basic Bootstrap modal example, that's how it's done http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

When trying to override the url in urls.py, did you place the override above or below the "url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))"? When I tried to override allauth the first time, I placed my code below that line, which doesn't work--going above that line worked.